# How much average power delivered to each antenna?

Tags: power, transmission-line

I am confused if the characteristic impedance of line 1 is simply 50 ohms. Also, I know that \$P_{av} = P_{av}^i + P_{av}^r\$, but I do not have the voltage amplitude \$|V_o^+| \$ so I am unsure how to proceed.

[image: Transmission Line Schematic]

Comment: Do you know how to figure out the effective input impedance of a line of known length with a known termination?

Comment: I know that the two loads simplify to 75/2. And that from there, the input impedance equals that of the new load. But I need to determine the characteristic impedance from there.

Comment: Suppose it is 25 ohms or 100 ohms, do you get a different answer for the equivalent impedance looking in to this network? Or for the power delivered to either antenna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you said,

> I know that the two loads simplify to 75/2. And that from there, the input impedance equals that of the new load.

So you know the effective impedance of the whole load network.

From that you can find the power delivered to the network. The only place in the network where this power can be absorbed is in the loads.

Now, looking at the symmetry of the problem, is there any reason to believe that antenna 1 receives more power than antenna 2, or vice versa?